# How to post msg on twitter using php

Tags: php, twitter

My below script for posting msg is not working. can anyone help me in this?

```
$username = ($_POST['t_user']);
$password = ($_POST['t_pass']);
$message = ($_POST['t_update']);

$url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml';
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=$message");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
if (empty($buffer)) {
    echo "<p align=\"center\" >".'Sorry, due to an error your Twitter status could not be updated! Please check your username/password!'."</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p align=\"center\">".'Your Twitter status has successfully been updated!'."</p>";
}
```

Comment: how does you html file look like?

Comment: it would probably help to be more descriptive than "is not working".  How is it not working?  Also, don't you need to go thru oAuth to post to Twitter like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspire from this tutorial:

**Creating a Simple Twitter App using oAuth and PHP**
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch to [OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq), quote from the page:

> We announced in December of 2009 the deprecation of Basic Auth. Its removal date from the platform is set for June 2010. We announced towards the end of June 2010 that we have postponed this until August 16th 2010.